# Variable selection and merging categories after the fact

Tags: categorical-data, stepwise-regression, fused-lasso

Notwithstanding the issues with certain variable selection procedures like stepwise regression, suppose you run some sort of variable selection to find significant categorical covariates in a regression. Then, you merge categories in order to increase the precision of your estimates.

Could this possibly be problematic, since the new coding may make the significant variable from the variable selection procedure insignificant?

Comment: There is a method adapted to your goal: The fused lasso, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160790/the-name-of-fused-lasso